# Eclipse not detecting MapActivity class

Tags: android, android-maps

I cannot get maps to work. In fact, according to Eclipse, theres no "google" package under "com". I have Google APIs installed for API level 15. Although i have set `minSdkVersion="10"`, my build target is 15.

This is my manifest. Do i need to add some .jar to make it work?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.arn.log"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name2" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

my activity, which doesn't get compiled. Ecilpse shows error even in importing MapActivity.

```
package com.arn.log;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class Map extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
}
```

I had installed google API of rev 2 for API 15. It had left a DOS window open permanently for very long. When i closed it, it showed some error, but now, SDK manager says that Google APIs are "installed". How do i make sure that this wasn't a bad install?

Comment: you can see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ maybe helpful

Comment: There's not enough info here to help you.  Can you even compile / run the app?  Are you getting any error messages?  If so, what kind?  What exactly is happening - are you just not seeing the map, or do you see the map but it's not responding? What does your layout file that has R.layout.map look like? Do you have an API key included in the layout? Is it tied to your debug keystore or some other keystore? etc, etc.

Comment: Also, did you try restarting eclipse after you installed the Google API's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set the target to Google APIs rather than Android-14.